# How to install `Happstack` on FreeBSD?

Tags: installation, packages, haskell

I'm trying to install Happstack on my FreeBSD box all day.
Finally I installed GHC 6.10.x. And Cabal 0.8.2. But failed on Happstack. These are errors.

```
%sudo ~/.cabal/bin/cabal install happstack
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure unix-2.4.1.0. It requires base >=4.2 && <4.4
For the dependency on base >=4.2 && <4.4 there are these packages:
base-4.2.0.0, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.2 and base-4.3.0.0. However none of
them are available.
base-4.2.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.2.0.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.2.0.2 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-4.3.0.0 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
%sudo ~/.cabal/bin/cabal install base
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: internal error: impossible
%sudo ~/.cabal/bin/cabal install base-4.3.0.0
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure base-4.3.0.0. It requires integer-simple -any
There is no available version of integer-simple that satisfies -any
%sudo ~/.cabal/bin/cabal install integer-simple
cabal: There is no package named integer-simple. Perhaps you need to run
'cabal update' first?
%
```

I did `cabal update` before all of these procedures.
What's the problem?

Comment: Already installed the `/usr/ports/lang/ghc` port? Here's a rough outline of getting GHC and Cabal installed and configured before installing happstack: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/installing-ghc-and-haskell-libraries.html#id688876

Comment: @Chris Thanks for care. But current GHC port is 6.10.4 has missing some important library packages to install Happstack. I decided to install binary distribution of 6.12.3 from GHC website. It's installing smoothly now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install latest version GHC(6.12.*). Use this [tarballs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_6_12_3#freebsd).

Comment: You're right. I'm already doing exactly what you said :)